# What is the index in QFuture::resultReadyAt(int index) indexing

Tags: c++, qt

```
void QFutureWatcher::resultReadyAt(int index)
```

This signal is emitted when the watched future reports a ready result at index. If the future reports multiple results, the index will indicate which one it is. Results can be reported out-of-order. To get the result, call `future().result(index);`

If a `QFutureWatcher` can only watch one `QFuture` instance, and the instance can only return one result, what is the index used for? I feel like I don't understand the way to properly use these two.

I would like to queue up multiple tasks that return their task results. If I have a list of tasks, I would like to associate the task result to the task list.

Comment: I do believe that this index is mostly related to the fact that a `QFuture` can have multiple results (check [QFuture::results()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfuture.html#results) for example). Since a `QFutureWatcher` is there just to monitor the future it also needs to have access to the multiple results that future may hold especially since this type of monitoring also provides you with signals and slots in case you want to propagate these results somewhere else.

Comment: @rbaleksandar thanks for the input. I don't see how there would be more than one result. The only way I see results getting populated is from the watched function returning. Is there a way to populate the results in another manner? I see nothing on documentation or examples showing how this index is ever used or how there is ever more than one result.

Answer (score 1):

First, note that `QFuture` is not a class whose original (non-copied) instances you create yourself: the instances are provided by the factory methods in the concurrent framework.

> If a QFutureWatcher can only watch one QFuture instance, and the instance can only return one result

That's not correct: the future returns however many results the asynchronous operation it wraps represents, and the `QFutureWatcher` has relevant signals `resultReadyAt` and `resultsReadyAt` that indicate these events asynchronously as they happen.

> I would like to queue up multiple tasks that return their task results. If I have a list of tasks, I would like to associate the task result to the task list.

`QtConcurrent::map` and `QtConcurrent::mapped` are what you're looking for: they provide the futures that have the multiple results.